# MobileServiceClient.invokeApi results in "No action was found on the controller"

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have custom API named **Foo**. When I'm trying to invoke this custom method from a Html page using javascript library of *MobileServiceClient* I get error:

> *"No action was found on the controller 'Foo' that matches the request"*

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.7.min.js"></script>
```

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#runAllTests').on('click', function() {
      var serviceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('<url>', '<key>');
      serviceClient.invokeApi('Foo', {
        body: {
          val1: 'value1',
          val2: 'value2',
        },
        method: 'GET'
      }).done(function(results) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(results);
      }, function(error) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(error);
      });

    });
  }); < /script>
```

However when I invoke this method from my Windows Store App, everything works fine.

The cross-origin resource sharing (cors) configured to *

UPDATE: It looks like I need to call this method specifying the parameters with the method name like:

```js
 serviceClient.invokeApi('Foo?val1=value1&val2=value2', {
   method: 'GET'
 })
```

Is it correct? Looks like even for the POST method I have to do the same unless my parameters have a complex type.

UPDATE 2: the definition of my custom API method as follows

```
[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]
public class FooController : ApiController
{
     public HttpResponseMessage Get(string val1, string val2)
     {
         //method body
     }
}
```

Comment: No you shouldn't have to, can you share the definition for your custom API?  Did you try using a tool like Postman to confirm the endpoint works as you'd expect?

Comment: Endpoind works. I've found out what is the issue here. I need to use 'parameters' property instead of 'body' to pass my parameters.

Comment: Parameters are converted to being sent via the querystring, so if you do want them to be sent via the body there is still an issue here.

Comment: @philipv, I've shared the definition of my custom API, see the UPDATE. So could you explain please? When I should use 'body' and when 'parameters'?

Comment: For an HTTP GET you have to use the querystring to send params, which the parameters object is automatically converted to: so [val1: 'a'] just becomes ?val1=a.  If you define the API as POST then either is supposed to work.

Comment: @phillipv, I've tried it with the POST it doesn't work. It works only when I pass the parameters via 'parameters'. I suppose that you need to use 'body' once you have a parameter of a complex type which is in my case not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found out that I need to pass these parameters not via **body** but via **parameters**. When you pass them via **body** or there is at least one of the parameters missing than you will get the 'Not found' error.

```js
serviceClient.invokeApi('Foo', {
  parameters: {
    val1: 'value1',
    val2: 'value2',
  },
  method: 'GET'
})
```